# Problems with handling html as response from a server in plain text

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am generating a html table serverside with Java and sending it as a JSON to the client. So my response is a plain text looking like this:

`<table class="table"></table><thead class="thead-dark"> <tr> <th scope="col">#</th> <th scope="col">Username</th> <th scope="col">Score</th> </tr> </thead><tbody> <tr> <th scope="row"> 1 </th> <td>Marvin</td> <td>3.0</td> </tr> <tr> <th scope="row"> 2 </th> <td>testerich</td> <td>3.0</td> </tr></tbody>`

My jQuery Script looks like this

```
if(reply.type === "highscores") {
        var el = reply.value.replace(/\s+/g,' ').trim();
        console.log(el);
        $('.score-table').empty();
        $('.score-table').html(el);
    }
```

the console.log outputs the plain text quoted above.

Now the expected behavior is that the table will be displayed in the div with the class "score-table" but instead its just showing the following:

`# Username Score 1 Marvin 3.0 2 testerich 3.0`

So it basicly stripped al the html tags off the string? Im searching for hours now but did not find a solution for this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is your html response, not jQuery or js. Look at the first row of your html:

```
<table class="table"></table>
```

This doesn't make any sense. It needs to look like this:

```html
<table class="table">
    <thead class="thead-dark"> 
        <tr> 
            <th scope="col">#</th> 
            <th scope="col">Username</th> 
            <th scope="col">Score</th> 
        </tr> 
    </thead>
    <tbody> 
        <tr> 
            <th scope="row"> 1 </th> 
            <td>Marvin</td>  
            <td>3.0</td> 
        </tr> 
        <tr> 
            <th scope="row"> 2 </th> 
            <td>testerich</td> 
            <td>3.0</td> 
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

You have closed the Table right after you opened it..

```
<table class="table"></table>
```

update your html to this:

```
<table class="table"><thead class="thead-dark"> <tr> <th scope="col">#</th> <th scope="col">Username</th> <th scope="col">Score</th> </tr> </thead><tbody> <tr> <th scope="row"> 1 </th> <td>Marvin</td> <td>3.0</td> </tr> <tr> <th scope="row"> 2 </th> <td>testerich</td> <td>3.0</td> </tr></tbody></table>
```